# How to get the height of the tabbar programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I've found out that the height of a UITabBar is 49px (or 50px, depending on the source).

Because I don't like to use too much hard-coded values in my code I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve the height of the tabbar programmatically.

Kind regards,
Niels R.

PS: The reason I'm asking is because I have a view controller (with a list view containing text fields) that is either simply pushed by the navigationcontroller (pushViewController) or presented as a modal (presentModalViewController). As soon as the keyboard show up, the size of the view is reduced, but I have to take into account that the tabbar is only visible when the view controller is pushed and not presented as a modal.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

I don't totally understand your P.S., but you can do:

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm happy that I'd figured it out myself in the meantime. Sometimes I get stuck on the most stupid things. :p

Comment: So what's the result? 50 or 49?

Comment: I think now it is: self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height

Comment: @NaXir With iPhone X that is no longer the case, so this is now very relevant.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to get the standard height for the UITabBar control then you can do:

```
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [UITabBarController new];
    CGFloat tabBarHeight = tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
```

Comment: I love this answer.  This is my favorite answer.  I recommend this answer if you are using Objective C

Comment: This is a bad answer though.. You create a completely new UITabBarController from scratch, which is entirely unnecessary and wasteful. If you need the height of a TabBar, you should get the height of your current tabBar.

Comment: Awesome also fixed iPhone X wrong tabbar size problem on first app install.

Answer (score 10):

prettier

```
CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame)
```

Comment: Thank you. And guided by xcode 8 beta it changed it to 'let tabBarHeight = (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame)!.height'

Comment: @kometen - be conscious of the force unwrap (ie: `!`) there, it can cause unwanted crashes

Answer (score 6):

check this in your vc

```
bottomLayoutGuide.length
```

Comment: As of iOS 11: "Use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor instead of bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor"

Comment: So, basically this should be `self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom` now.

Answer (score 3):

In `Swift 3`, you can retrieve the height of the `UITabBar` with this code below.

`self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.size.height`

Which will return a `CGFloat` value of the height

Answer (score 1):

If an object is based on UIView (which most visual elements in the library are), you can get the size from the ivar "frame".

Answer (score 1):

`UITabBar` is inherited from `UIView` as long as you mhave access to your UITabBar instance you can access and modify the frame of UITabBar,

```
CGRect myRect = myTabBar.frame;
```

Comment: I have a TabbarController subclass, this line gives me full view frame say 320x480

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the intrinsicContentSize property of the tab bar like this

```
let tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.intrinsicContentSize.height
```