# Getting incorrect value for height of tabbar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have the following class that I use in order to find the height of a tabBar at the bottom of my screen:

```
import UIKit

class TabsController: UITabBarController
{
    internal static var tabBarHeight: CGFloat = 0

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        TabsController.tabBarHeight = self.view.frame.height
        print(TabsController.tabBarHeight)
    }

}
```

The only reason I have the class is so that I can access the `tabBarHeight` variable.
 I created the class after seeing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388152/how-to-get-the-height-of-the-tabbar-programmatically).

For some reason, the print statement displays 667.0 instead of a correct value. How do I get the correct tabbar height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look back at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5388171/4082770) to that post you will see it is accessing self.tabBar on the UITabBarController, rather than the self.view. The view will encompass the tab bar and it's currently displayed content.